# Hide Fieldset's with JavaScript, when radio-button is checked, without onchange

Tags: javascript, html, visibility, onchange

I'm trying to hide a specific fieldset when one of the two radio-buttons is checked in a html form.
I use two radio-buttons with the id's: 'forproject' and 'forinternship'.

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Sign up</legend>
<label><input type="radio" onchange="hideInternship(this)" id="forproject" name="register" >project</label>
<label><input type="radio" onchange="hideProject(this)" id="forinternship" name="register" >internship</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="project">
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="internship">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I wrote two JavaScript functions in an external js.file to hide one of the fieldset's when a radio-button is checked, using onchange (in the html).

```
function hideProject(x) {
    if (x.checked)
    {
    document.getElementById('project').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('internship').style.visibility='visible';    
    } 
}

function hideInternship(x) {
    if (x.checked)
    {
    document.getElementById('internship').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('project').style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine, but i want to control the visibility of those fieldset's completely in the js.file. So there is no onchange or onclick in my html.

Does anyone have a tip?

Comment: Are you using jQuery in this project?

Comment: Nope, not allowed.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('forproject').addEventListener('onChange', hideInternship)
function hideInternship(event) {
    if (event.target.checked)
    {
    document.getElementById('internship').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('project').style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
```

=]

Comment: Thanks for you fast reply.
Sadly I get an Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: are you loading your JS file on the bottom of your page ?

Comment: That's it, sorry my mistake! Thanks a lot

Comment: =D <3 was a pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You can "attach" a function to the onclick on your JavaScript file.

A simple (and crude) example of how this works would be to include on your JS external file (and outside of your functions) the following:

```
document.getElementById('forinternship').onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked)
    {
    document.getElementById('internship').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('project').style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
document.getElementById('forproject').onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked)
    {
    document.getElementById('project').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('internship').style.visibility='visible';    
    } 
}
```

With that you can remove the onclick attribute on your HTML elements.
and you can get rid of those functions (they are being created directly on the onclick on the example code).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but i get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: @Maarten, the error indicates that `document.getElementById('forinternship')` or `document.getElementById('forproject')`are not finding the input-radio elements. Did you chage the HTML of the example on your question? Anyway, I see that you already found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider delegation, where a single listener is on a parent element:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('f0').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var tgt = evt.target;
    if (tgt.id == 'forproject' || tgt.id == 'forinternship') {
      document.getElementById('project').style.visibility = document.getElementById('forproject').checked? 'visible':'hidden';
      document.getElementById('internship').style.visibility = document.getElementById('forinternship').checked? 'visible':'hidden';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset id="f0">
    <legend>Sign up</legend>
    <label for="forproject"><input type="radio" id="forproject" name="register" >project</label>
    <label for="forinternship"><input type="radio" id="forinternship" name="register" >internship</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="project">Project</fieldset>
  <fieldset id="internship">Internship</fieldset>
</form>
```